# TypeError: (0 , _x) is not a function in jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to export a function that is a const inline function and use it in a jest module, but I am getting the error
`TypeError: (0 , _utils.reverseMapper) is not a function`

I don't know why this happens because the function I am calling doesn't rely on/ call this function at all, and its not in the same module as getJson()

I have tried to import vs require (since its a variable) but neither of these work

so far I am doing the following

```
import { getJson } from "../myUtils";

jest.mock('../myUtils', () => ({
  getJson: jest.fn(),
}));
```

then in my test:

```
const configs = {
  policies:['something']
};


 it('Failed to load the userid', async () => {
    ObjectIdDecrypt.mockImplementationOnce(() => '6536');
    mpds.getBizInfo.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(info));
    user.userSearch.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve(errorResponse)
    );
    getJson.mockImplementation( () => configs);
    try {
      await somethingElse(
        {
          input: {
            timezone: 'America/New_York',
          },
        },
        { req: getMockReq() }
      );
      expect.fail('Expected to throw error');
    } catch (err) {
      expect(err).toBeDefined();
      expect(err.message).toEqual('User does not exist');
      expect(err.extensions.name).toEqual('INVALID_REQUEST');
    }
  });
```

hoping someone can help me understand why jest is throwing this error

Comment: Which line is giving you that error?